# Use of wilcard for generic class, with its generic being also generic class

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have a generic class with its generic still being a generic class, like
`List<ConsumerRecord<String, SpecificRecord>>` or `List<ConsumerRecord<String, Object>>`

I need to write a method signature to accept both, not requiring second-level generic.

For one level of generics, `List<? extends T>`, with T being Object, so `List<?>` would be fine.

However with two levels, `List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>>` fails to compile.

My simple solution was generic method, but is there a cleaner way to do so?

```
protected <T> String printOffsetsForMessages(List<ConsumerRecord<String, T>> records)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another level of extends:

```
List<? extends ConsumerRecord<?, ?>>
```